# How to show custom amount of SVG circles to each individual user?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, svg

I am currently putting together a site that will host users. Each user will have a profile page that will display an array of SVG circles, with each user also having a corresponding SVG_number in there own row in the users table of the database.

So for example if User1 has an SVG_number of 20 stored in the database, then they will see 20 circles on their profile page.

My question concerns the addition of new users, and how to have the site differentiate between these users to display the right amount of circles after querying the SVG_number?

And will I have to pre-build all of these SVG elements, hide them somewhere, and have the right one displayed relative to the users SVG_number through some sort of IF statement?

Im not looking for specific code, just a general idea of how I would go about organising this?

Quite new to programming, so I'm not totally clear on what languages this would involve, or what process. any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: This video has nothing to do with circles, but please watch https://youtu.be/8ZtInClXe1Q

Answer (score 1):

You should use the programming language available for your server. In most cases, this will be `PHP`.

You need to make the .svg document end in `.php`, so you have a file like `circles.php`

Then in the document you need:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>';

$number = ... (get this from the database. Search for PHP and MySQL)
?>
<svg>
   ... your svg code ...
   <?php if ($number > 10) { ?>
     .. sample circle ...
   <?php } ?>
</svg>
```

Comment: Okay thank you this is a good starting point. So will I need to have circles.php file for each varying amount of circles I need? And Is it possible to display this circles.php file within the users profile page?

Comment: No. You need one file.
In that file, you need to find out how many circles to display.

Comment: the only block of circles I currently have is written into the html code of the users homepage, will I have to right in all the different amounts in blocks of code on this file and display them via a conditional statement?

Comment: Yes, this is an option.

If they follow a pattern, you can compute them on the fly using a `for` loop. It provides you with an index counting from 0 to any limit you set. You can then use `sin`, `cos` and others to compute your circles.

Comment: Okay thank you for the advice I will try to implement this. Would the best way be to set the id of the svg, say id="30" for the 30 circles, and then save the SVG_number in the database as 30 for that user, and say that when the users SVG_number = 30 then display the '#30" element?

Comment: This depends on the framework you are already using. It is possible to do it that way. Mind that ids should start with a letter, so call it `id="circle-30"`